# How to pass stackPane reference to another Class method

Tags: java, javafx, methods, pass-by-reference

Im working on some project of traffic simulation, and have a problem with call a method in another class,

```
    public class Grafika extends Application {        
    private StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

      Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 731, 779);

      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.setTitle("PN");
      primaryStage.show();

      Image image = new Image("file:plN_v3.png");
      ImageView iv = new ImageView();
      iv.setImage(image);
      stackPane.getChildren().add(iv);

      firstPath(stackPane);}

    public void setStackPane() {
        this.stackPane = stackPane;
        }
```

this is my stage with stackPane where im adding moving objects

```
    public void firstPath(StackPane stackPane) {
         Circle car = new Circle(5, 5, 5);
         setCar(car);

         stackPane.getChildren().add(car);

         Path path = new Path();
         path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(380, -105));
         path.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(30, -140, 100, -300, -20, -140)); //first  for car
         path.getElements().add(new LineTo(-315, 400));

         pathT(path, car);
    }


     public void pathT(Object path, Object car) {

        PathTransition pathT = new PathTransition();
        pathT.setDuration(Duration.millis(15000));
        pathT.setPath((Shape) path);
        pathT.setNode((Node) car);


        pathT.setOrientation
        (PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        pathT.setAutoReverse(true);
        pathT.play();
    }
```

there is a example of path to move a "car".

```
    public class App{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
{

   Grafika.launch(Grafika.class, args);
   Grafika g = new Grafika();

   StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
   g.setStackPane();
   g.firstPath(stackPane);

}   }
```

And when im calling firstPath in class Grafika it's seems fine, but problem is when i try to call this method in another class

Comment: What exactly is the error ? If you want to call this method in another class you need to pass the stackPane reference there. You create StackPane object in Graphica the function firstPath() takes StackPane as a argument so to use firstPath in another class you shall need stackPane reference from the class Grafika or to create another StackPane object in the new class itself. Show us your other class code that you want to call firstPath method.

Comment: `new Grafika()` ← That is not permitted.  You can’t create your own Application objects.  The only way an Application may be created is by JavaFX.  You make that creation happen by calling Application.launch, which you’re already doing.  If you want to create a new StackPane, do it in the `start` method.

Comment: `Application.launch` does not return until the GUI is shut down. Adding some code modifying the gui later is pointless. You should start running logic like this in the `start` (or in some cases in the `init`) method of the `Application`. The `Application` serves as entry point of the app. The instance is constructed by the `Application.launch` method, so creating one yourself won't give you access to the instance `start` is called for.